# Bash - How to get STDOUT from a background ruby script

Tags: ruby, bash, background-process

I need to run one ruby script in background, but I want to see its output in real time.

I wrote a simple test called `loop.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

(1..4).each do
  puts "loop!"
  sleep 1
end
```

Whose foreground output is:

```
sony@sonymint:~/test$ ./loop.rb
loop!
loop!
loop!
loop!
```

But I can't see it in background:

```
sony@sonymint:~/test$ ./loop.rb &
[2] 3935
sony@sonymint:~/test$
```

However I can see the `ping`'s output in background:

```
sony@sonymint:~/test$ ping google.com &
[2] 3734                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
sony@sonymint:~/test$ PING google.com (64.233.190.113) 56(84) bytes of data.                                                                                                                                                                                                 
64 bytes from ce-in-f113.1e100.net (64.233.190.113): icmp_seq=1 ttl=42 time=79.6 ms                                                                                                                                                                                          
64 bytes from ce-in-f113.1e100.net (64.233.190.113): icmp_seq=2 ttl=42 time=79.5 ms                                                                                                                                                                                          
64 bytes from ce-in-f113.1e100.net (64.233.190.113): icmp_seq=3 ttl=42 time=81.7 ms
```

So, two questions:

1. Why can I see the output of `ping` and not the output of `loop.rb`?
2. How to get the output of `loop.rb` in background in Bash?

**UPDATE**

@TomLord in comment is right: there is some odd system configuration. Locally my `ruby` is not a plain-installed ruby interpreter; it's a script which runs `ruby` inside a Docker container. So it can be a Docker issue. I tested on a machine with a plain-installed ruby interpreter and it worked fine. I'll investigate Docker buffering issues next.

Comment: Works for me just fine.

Comment: Works fine for me, too. Perhaps you have some odd system configuration? (But even then, I have no idea why `ping` would work if this doesn't?!)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/972968/why-does-a-background-process-started-in-bash-print-stdout-to-screen#answer-972980

Comment: Try a longer string in the Ruby test; you may have a buffering issue where you aren't letting the program run long enough for the buffer to fill and write to standard output.

Comment: @TomLord you're right, see my update.

Comment: @chepner I really liked your suggestion and tried it (with 4KB and 8KB), but it was not the case. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem and the solution.

The problem:

1. Why can I see the output of `ping` and not the output of `loop.rb`?

Because my local `ruby` is not a genuine ruby interpreter, but it's a script which runs `ruby` inside a docker container (easier to manage than using `rvm` IMHO). So it's a docker pipe buffer issue.

The solution:

2. How to get the output of `loop.rb` in background in Bash?

By using the [`unbuffer` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25375/10881):

```
sony@sonymint:~/test$ unbuffer ./loop.rb & 
[3] 7262
sony@sonymint:~/test$ loop! 
loop! 
loop! 
loop!
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this at the beginning of your script:

```
STDOUT.sync = true
```

This should disable buffering on the Ruby script's standard output.  That buffering is normally done by your system's libc if it detects that it is not being run in an interactive shell.